# How can I calculate the mid-point between two dates in php

Tags: php

How can I calculate the mid-point between two dates in PHP

In Java Script we do -

```
var midpoint = new Date((date1.getTime() + date2.getTime()) / 2);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mathematically it's exactly the same - are you asking us to convert the actual code to PHP?

Comment: Is the same but in php, search "date php"

Comment: You've given no indication of your current skill level with PHP so it's very hard gauge how much information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way for this -

```
$daysDiff = diffDateTime($StartDate, $EndDate); 
$midDaysDiff = round($daysDiff['days']/2); 
$midDate = strtotime(date("m/d/Y", strtotime($StartDate)) . "+ $midDaysDiff Days"); 

function diffDateTime($StartDate, $EndDate)
{
    // returns diff between two dates in days...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$midPoint = (strtotime($date1) + strtotime($date2))/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done fairly similarly to javascript actually try this

```
$midpoint = ($date1 + $date2) / 2
```

This assuming $date1 and $date2 are timestamps ( the same that is generated from getTime() )