# how to get half DateTime between two dates?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have current datetime and delivery datetime

```
$del_time = $this->input->post('bid_time');    
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

i want exact half of datetime in between current datetime and delivery datetime in Y-m-d H:i:s period in php

Comment: what do you mean by half time? would you like to give an example with two times?

Comment: have you *tried* anything so far? like *calculating the difference, dividing it by two and adding it to one date*?

Comment: You have a few examples about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798213/how-can-i-calculate-the-mid-point-between-two-dates-in-php and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967857/calculating-midpoint-of-two-times i hope it helps to you as a valid start point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$del_time           = $this->input->post('bid_time');   //for ex '2016-12-01 12:30:00';
$now                = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$loc_del_date_time  = strtotime($del_time);
$loc_curr_date_time = strtotime($now);
$loc_mid_time       = ($loc_del_date_time + $loc_curr_date_time) / 2;
$loc_mid_time       = round($loc_mid_time);
echo $loc_new_date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $loc_mid_time);
```

Thanks